# Updating a nested record in mongodb array when you don't know the document index

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I want to update the record of a nested document, my document looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "60753fd9b249ad0dfa1eeb48",
    "name": "Random Name 1",
    "email": "randomname1@zmel.kom",
    "likings": [
      {
        "breakfast": {
          "eat": "oats",
          "drink": "milk"
        }
      },
      {
        "lunch": {
          "eat": "beef",
          "drink": "pepsi"
        }
      },
      {
        "dinner": {
          "eat": "steak",
          "drink": "champagne"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "60753fd9b249ad0dfa1eeb58",
    "name": "Random Name 2",
    "email": "randomname2@zmel.kom",
    "likings": [
      {
        "breakfast": {
          "eat": "cereals",
          "drink": "coffee"
        }
      },
      {
        "lunch": {
          "eat": "salad",
          "drink": "hot-water"
        }
      },
      {
        "dinner": {
          "eat": "biryani",
          "drink": "apple juice"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to update the value of `drink` for `dinner` for `Random Name 2` but I don't know the index of dinner, it could be above the `lunch`, it could be just below the `breakfast`.
Here's what I have tried in Python :

```py
oid = data[0]                # fetched from flask form
to_be_updated = data[1]      # fetched from flask form
update_value = data[2]       # fetched from flask form
condition = {"_id" : oid}
update_value = {
    "$set" : {
        f"likings.{to_be_updated}.drink" : update_value
    }
}
response = mongo.db.food.update(condition, update_value)
```

but the error I am getting is:
`pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot create field 'dinner' in element <complete element description>`
What my other strategy that I am planning on using is, only match ID and then update `likings` by keeping the values that are no needed to be changed as it is and altering that value that i want to change. But this approach seems too obvious and semantically wrong since I am using `not updating but updating` kind of strategy i.e disturbing the collection schema for no actual reason. Is there a way to do that or should I just continue with what I am thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO**: [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6syAEmnJwDp)

First of all, there are errors in your JSON.

### JSON

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60753fd9b249ad0dfa1eeb48",
    "name": "Random Name 1",
    "email": "randomname1@zmel.kom",
    "likings": [
      {
        "breakfast": {
          "eat": "oats",
          "drink": "milk"
        }
      },
      {
        "lunch": {
          "eat": "beef",
          "drink": "pepsi"
        }
      },
      {
        "dinner": {
          "eat": "steak",
          "drink": "champagne"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "60753fd9b249ad0dfa1eeb58",
    "name": "Random Name 2",
    "email": "randomname2@zmel.kom",
    "likings": [
      {
        "breakfast": {
          "eat": "cereals",
          "drink": "coffee"
        }
      },
      {
        "lunch": {
          "eat": "salad",
          "drink": "hot-water"
        }
      },
      {
        "dinner": {
          "eat": "biryani",
          "drink": "apple juice"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Try this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": "Random Name 2",
  "likings.dinner": {
    "$exists": true
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "likings.$.dinner.drink": "PEPSI"
  }
})
```

You can change `dinner` to whatever field you want to update accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, refactor `likings` from a list to an object.

If you can't refactor, check out the `$` and `$[]` positional operators https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/