# How to pull a nested Document

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

Referring to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070896/updating-a-document-record-in-mongodb-when-you-dont-know-the-document-index-usi), Now I want to remove `dinner` from `Random Name 2`, how can I do that:
Here's what i tried:

```py
din_val = data[0]
condition = {
    "username" : session['user']["username"],
    f"likings.{din_val}" : {
        "$exists" : True
    }
}
update_value = {
    "$pull" : {
        f"likings.$" : din_val
    }
}
response = mongo.db.appname.update(condition, update_value)
```

But the error I am receiving is
`pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 2, 'errmsg': 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/uYexli31rsc

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
db.collection.update(
{ "name": "Random Name 2" },
{ $pull: { "likings": { dinner: { $exists: true } } }
})
```